# How to show all dependencies, third party of react native app on Settings app

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I want to show all dependencies, third party of react native app on Settings app same as https://github.com/mono0926/LicensePlist.
Are React Native support it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily list all of your project dependencies. The tricky (and not sure how feasible) part would be to get the dependencies of your dependencies (and so forth).

If you want to get your own dependencies, you can use this code:

```
import packageJson from '../package.json'

const getAllDependencyNames = ({ dependencies, devDependencies }) => [
  ...Object.keys(dependencies),
  ...Object.keys(devDependencies),
];

// If getAllDependencies is a class function, use this.getAllDependencies
const myDependencies = getAllDependencyNames(packageJson);
```

This will merge all dependencies and devDependencies into a single Array. You can then iterate over them to render them.

```
render() {
  <FlatList
    data={myDependencies}
    renderItem={({dependency}) => <Text>{dependency}</Text>}
  />
}
```

Comment: I understand it. But i want to show it on Setting app.

Comment: @jefffreyallen No, i can't find any solution.

Comment: I [wrote a script](https://gist.github.com/jefflewis/50c6b49209568d04bb5fb137e947336b) that utilizes [nlf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nlf) to handle this. It outputs plist files that will be picked up by the settings bundle from the LicensePlist package.